# jQuery :first and :last selector

Tags: jquery

```
$('div#nutrition-fact-content table tr:first td:first').addClass('product-volume');
$('div#nutrition-fact-content table tr:first td:last').addClass('flavor-name');
```

In the above code, the second line of jQuery applies the class. The td before it never receives the class. I also tried just tr:first to class the row, and that doesn't get a class either. Why not?

Comment: what does the html look like?

Comment: How do you know the class is not applied? Have you had a look at the DOM? Maybe you have a typo in your CSS file.

Comment: I used Firebug to inspect. flavor-name is definitely applied.

Comment: Inline with what @FelixKling inferred, [I didn't have any trouble](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/BhNPV/) getting it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('div#nutrition-fact-content table tr:first td').first().addClass('product-volume');
$('div#nutrition-fact-content table tr:first td').last().addClass('flavor-name');
```

**UPDATE 2**
If you dont have jQuery > 1.4.4:
Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RmwtK/)

Works like a charm :-)

```
$children = $('div#nutrition-fact-content table tr:first').children().length -1;

$($('div#nutrition-fact-content table tr:first').children()[0]).addClass('product-volume');
$($('div#nutrition-fact-content table tr:first').children()[$children]).addClass('flavor-name');
```

Comment: .first() is not a function says Firebug.

Comment: Not using 1.4, this is a Drupal 6 site. 1.3.2 I believe.

Comment: ahhh ok. you dont state that in your question ^_^

Comment: @Kevin. my final update should work for u. was tested with 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

The selectors seem to work when I tested them [here](http://stevewellens.xtreemhost.com/jQuerySelectorTester.htm).
Are you sure everything else is OK?

Comment: what version of jquery does that test?